# How to get a string in the output of curl command in Unix shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, curl, awk, grep

I am looking to cut the task number which is highlighted in the output. However, normal grep or sed commands or redirection to text file for getting the desired output is not working. As the curl is writing on the terminal screen, these operations arent working. Please suggest.

vcap@jumpbox-sagdf-staging:~ $ **curl -v -s -k 'https://admin:88uudjdjd@10.19.1.1:25555/deployments/concourse/vms?format=full'**
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

- Trying 10.19.1.1....
- Connected to 10.19.1.1 (10.19.1.1) port 25555 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: none

  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
- SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
- Server certificate:
- subject: CN=director
- start date: 2017-06-20 13:19:23 GMT
- expire date: 2019-06-20 13:19:23 GMT
- issuer: CN=rootCA
- SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
- Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'

> GET /deployments/concourse/vms?format=full HTTP/1.1
>
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46OHdId1lEVlIwakJCZ3c=
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
>
> Host: 10.19.1.1:25555
>
> Accept: */*

>

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

- Server nginx is not blacklisted

< Server: nginx

< Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 04:07:19 GMT

< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

< Content-Length: 0

< Connection: keep-alive

< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="BOSH Director"

< Location: https://10.19.1.1/tasks/**1017317**

< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<

- Connection #0 to host 10.19.1.1 left intact

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to extract the piece on the right of the right-most slash of the `Location:` response header, I would use this:

```
curl -so /dev/null -w "%{redirect_url}\n" $URL | sed 's:.*/::g'
```

so that with your original URL use case it would look like (I added the -k back in this version):

```
curl -kso /dev/null -w "%{redirect_url}\n" 'https://admin:88uudjdjd@10.19.1.1:25555/deployments/concourse/vms?format=full' | sed 's:.*/::g'
```

(Do note that you've exposed your user name and password to the world here...)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your inputs ... Just curious to know what I have to substitute in "%{redirect_url}\n" $URL  while executing ?

Comment: Yep .. the details provided here are dummy :)  I am trying to check with two deployments like this in a loop ..

for i in cf concourse

do

curl -kso /dev/null -w "%{redirect_url}\n" 
'https://admin:88uudjdjd@10.19.1.1:25555/deployments/$i/vms?format=full' | sed 's:.*/::g'

done

but it is not providing the output. Please suggest.

Comment: the shell doesn't expand `$i` when put within single quotes. Use double quotes?